# Deploying Qt app with QtMultimedia on Linux

Tags: qt, deployment, qtmultimedia

I tried to deploy an application Qt (5.3) on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) which use QtMultimedia
I have first deployed a simple application (Hello World) to understand. I have had no problem ro run the application on Pc without install Qt.
In the same way, I have tried to desploy my whole app but I have a problem when I want execute my application :

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtMultimedia" is not installed
```

I have understand the problem comes to QtMultimedia but I don't find which library I have forgotten.
I have the tree for my project deployment :

```
- myApp/.
    - libs
        - libQt5Multimedia.so.5.3.1
        - libQt5MultimediaQuick_p.so.5.3.1
        - libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5.3.1
        - ...
    - myApp
    - Makefile
    - ...
```

Of course, my app run correctly on machine (ubuntu 13.10). 
My app.pro :

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick multimedia


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    datacube.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    img_interface.qrc \
    img_contenu.qrc \
    media.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    datacube.h
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Install the **qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin** package and you should be good to go

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin
```

Found the same issue here as well:
https://github.com/robotology/yarp/issues/263

Comment: FWIW: I couldn't run the MakerBot digitizer software from MakerBot.  Was silently crashing at startup.  I was able to figure out this was the missing package; the digitizer software is running now.