# module "QtMultimedia" is not installed

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, qtmultimedia

I've installed Qt and Qtcreator on a Raspberry Pi 3 using the normal *apt-get install* method. Everything seems to work fine except when I try to build the declarative-camera example or other multimedia examples I get an error saying `module "QtMultimedia" is not installed`. Then the empty white application window pops up.

I've tried installing and reinstalling all the required packages such as `libqt5multimedia5`, `qtmultimedia5-dev`, `etc` and it just says they are installed with newest version.

Has anyone had success with getting qt multimedia working on raspberry pi?

**Edit:**
I tried using the suggested solution of: 
`sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin`

That gives me an error of:
`E: Unable to locate package qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying Qt app with QtMultimedia on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868981/deploying-qt-app-with-qtmultimedia-on-linux)

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-get instal libqt5multimedia5-plugins qml-module-qtmultimedia`, What version of Qt5 do you have?

Answer (score 5):

This seemed to work run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins qml-module-qtmultimedia
```

I was missing libqt5multimedia5-plugins

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Do you know if there is any way to get this to work using `pip install`? I have an application that uses QtMultimedia.QSoundEffect and is installed via pypi/pip

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Qt Maintenance Tool (It is already installed on your pc when you downloaded Qt)

[image]

2. Login to your Qt account and hit next
3. Select Add or Remove Components, next
4. Go to `Qt` -> (The Qt version you installed) -> `Additional Libraries` and select `Qt Multimedia` like this (I'm using Qt 6.3.1)

[image]

5. Hit next to install it