# How to install QMultimedia on ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, installation, cmake

I have a c++ project in which I want to use QMediaPlayer, but when I include it its give me error saying

```
 fatal error: QMediaPlayer: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <QMediaPlayer>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have the Qt package in my home directory('~/Qt') it is 6.1.2 version, I checked its `include` and wasn't able to find QtMultimedia.

I tried to install QtMultimedia with `sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev` after the installation was complete, still I wasn't able to find QMultimedia in `~/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64/include/`
I have tried this [module "QtMultimedia" is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042974/module-qtmultimedia-is-not-installed)

Even though this I edited my CMakeLists.txt to find it

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS
    Core
    Gui
    Multimedia
    Widgets
    Concurrent
    Network
    REQUIRED
)

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS
    Core
    Gui
    Widgets
    Multimedia
    Concurrent
    Network
    REQUIRED
)
```

when rebuilding it with `cmake --build .` it gave me the  same error ie

```
fatal error: QMediaPlayer: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <QMediaPlayer>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So instead of including it this time I directly used it but it still gave me error

```
‘QMediaPlayer’ does not name a type
   20 |         QMediaPlayer player;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: "I have the Qt package in my home directory('~/Qt') it is 6.1.2 version" - So you have **custom** QT installation. Package manager `apt` provides **system** installation of things, so it won't add files to your custom QT installation. You can easily [find](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=QMediaPlayer&mode=&suite=focal&arch=any), that package `qtmultimedia5-dev` provides required file at `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If i move it manually will it work? there were 4 folders starting with multimedia

Comment: "If i move it manually will it work?" - I won't except a subpackage for Qt5 will fork for Qt6. Actually, your `find_package` call seems to be OK: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmediaplayer.html. Make sure that you have appropriate `target_link_libraries` call too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `target_link_libraries(project Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)` this is correct right?

Comment: Please, look into documentation page I referred to: it suggests `target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::Multimedia)`.